# Nested floating divs not working

Tags: html, css

On the site I'm currently coding I have a centered DIV containing a float left column and a smaller float right column. This works fine.

In the Left floating column, I have a further float left column, containing an bio image, and a float right text column containing the bio text.

However, I am at the point of throwing my computer out of the window because the last two bio divs are sitting on top of each other, with the text *underneath* the photo instead of floating next to it.

I have put every combination of clear divs and overflow: hidden; I can reasonably think of, but to no avail.

The page in question is here: http://test.phantomlimb.net/about.php and the CSS is here: http://test.phantomlimb.net/phantom.css

I would greatly appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction to solve this annoying conundrum before I break down and **gasp!** accomplish the same effect using tables in around 3 minutes!!!

PS I'm more of a designer than a coder, so please feel free to explain things as you would to a child.

Comment: Please show your code and maybe create a fiddle also.

Comment: jsfiddle.net | There you can recreate the problem, save it and add the link to your question. That way, It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Please see the [ask] page on help for tips on asking a good question for Stack Overflow. The main thing to remember is that Stack Overflow is for asking questions that will be of use for many people in the future. Right now, since the only code is something on another server, it will likely be of no used for others in the future. Besides jsfiddle, there is also [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), which are built into Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? 
Add float: left; to your .bioleft class in phantom.css

Alternatively add float: right; to your .bioright class

Comment: Show an example of what you're saying.

Comment: Ah! You indirectly helped me solve the question! I looked closer at the class in the CSS, and realised I had missed the colon out of float: left; and float: right;

Comment: I can't believe I spent five hours trying to solve a problem my own typing idiocy created. Thanks again to the responders and sorry for wasting your time!!

Comment: Glad that I helped you indirectly solve the question! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing colons in your css file. e.g. you have

```
.bioleft {
    float left; /* HERE */
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    display: block; 
}

.bioright {
    float right; /* AND HERE */
    width: 70%;
    background: cyan;
    display: block; 
}
```

You should have `float: left;` and `float: right;`

Comment: Yes, I realised shortly after posting the question! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IT is because of improper syntax you have float left; it should be float: left;

Comment: Yes, I realised shortly after posting the question! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using floated divs for the container left and right divs, then just use inline blocks for the divs inside the floated divs?

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

And

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#img,#content {
    display:inline-block;
}
#img {
    width: 100px;
}
#content {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

That should put the image and the content side by side, but they will be treated as a block div.

You could actually put both the image and content divs inside their own container div and name that biog as the id, to create its own 'block'